# Xen Hypervisor videoram not giving higher resolutions

Tags: xen

I have the following configuration (output is from `xm list --long`):

```
(hvm
        (kernel '')
        (superpages 0)
        (videoram 16)
        (hpet 0)
        (stdvga 1)
        (loader /usr/lib/xen/boot/hvmloader)
        (smbios_firmware '')
        (xen_platform_pci 1)
        (nestedhvm 0)
        (rtc_timeoffset 0)
        (pci ())
        (hap 1)
        (localtime 0)
        (xenpaging_extra ())
        (actmem 0)
        (pci_msitranslate 1)
        (oos 1)
        (apic 1)
        (acpi_firmware '')
        (usbdevice mouse)
        (xenpaging_file '')
        (timer_mode 1)
        (vpt_align 1)
        (serial pty)
        (vncunused 1)
        (boot c)
        (pae 1)
        (viridian 0)
        (acpi 1)
        (vnc 1)
        (nographic 0)
        (watchdog_action reset)
        (nomigrate 0)
        (usb 1)
        (tsc_mode 0)
        (guest_os_type default)
        (device_model /usr/lib/xen/bin/qemu-dm)
        (keymap en-us)
        (pci_power_mgmt 0)
        (xauthority /root/.Xauthority)
        (isa 0)
        (notes (SUSPEND_CANCEL 1))
    )
```

Notice that stdvga=1 and videoram=16.
Here is the `lspci -s 00:02.0 -vvv`  output from the Guest:

```
lspci -s 00:02.0 -vvv
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Device 1234:1111 (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: XenSource, Inc. Device 0001
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Region 0: Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
```

I am still only able to get resolutions of 1024x768 and 800x600. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my configuration... It works as expected.

(hvm
            (kernel '')
            (superpages 0)
            (videoram 16)
            (hpet 0)
            (stdvga 1)
            (loader /usr/lib/xen-4.1/boot/hvmloader)
            (xen_platform_pci 1)
            (rtc_timeoffset 0)
            (pci ())
            (hap 1)
            (localtime 0)
            (timer_mode 1)
            (pci_msitranslate 1)
            (oos 1)
            (apic 1)
            (sdl 0)
            (vpt_align 1)
            (vncunused 1)
            (boot dc)
            (pae 1)
            (viridian 1)
            (acpi 1)
            (vnc 1)
            (nographic 0)
            (nomigrate 0)
            (usb 1)
            (tsc_mode 0)
            (guest_os_type default)
            (device_model /usr/lib/xen-4.1/bin/qemu-dm)
            (pci_power_mgmt 0)
            (xauthority /root/.Xauthority)
            (isa 0)
            (notes (SUSPEND_CANCEL 1))
        )

Answer (score 0):

Why not connect your VM via XDMCP?

Use Xnest or Xephyr:

Xnest :1 -geometry 1280x800 -query 10.0.1.x

Xephyr :1 -screen 1280x1024 -query 192.168.1.x

The only thing you have to do is to enable remote login in your VM or DomainU by manually editing /etc/gdm/custom.cfg or using the gdmsetup GUI program. Here CentOS 5 DomainU is taken as an example. In Ubuntu things will be a little differrent.

This approach is very different to VNC which is like Microsoft's RDP (screen capture) while XDMCP utilizes your Domain0's graphic power to assist DomainU system. That is comparable to Xen VGA passthrough in terms of performance.

Remember X11 was specifically designed to be used over network connections rather than on an integral or attached display device. X features network transparency: the machine where an application (the client application, for instance Firefox in your VM or DomainU) runs can differ from the user's local machine (the display server, that is the X11 in your Domain0). This approach allows both 2D and 3D operations to be fully accelerated on the user's local X server.